# Visual C++: Warn against implicit integer-floating conversions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, warnings

I have an unfortunate case where API A uses integer timeouts in milliseconds, and API B uses floating-point timeouts in seconds.  I'd like the compiler to issue a warning against implicit conversions to stop me from passing the wrong timeout to the wrong API.  For example:

```
int timeout_ms = 1000;
double timeout_sec = 1.0;

a_func(timeout_ms); // OK
a_func(timeout_sec); // warning
```

Is there a warning in MSVC I can enable to get this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just write a little wrapper that ensures you just can't ever get it wrong?

```
class Timeout {
    int msec;
public:
    Timeout(int milliseconds) : msec(milliseconds) {}
    operator double() { return msec / 1000.0; }
    operator int() { return msec; }
};


Timeout tout(1000);
afunc(tout);
```

Comment: This is a nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

4244 will give you the warning you are looking for.

If you are using Visual Studio 2013 then thanks to the magic of C++11 another better alternative exists, which is deleted functions.  This will make it an error to try to call the function incorrectly in a way that is portable and will not depend on compiler flags.

```
int timeout_ms = 1000;
double timeout_sec = 1.0;

void a_func(int);
void a_func(double) = delete;

int main(void)
{
    a_func(timeout_ms); // OK
    a_func(timeout_sec); // error C2280 : 'void a_func(double)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
}
```